# how to block an application in android after using several times?

Tags: android, security

I created an application for pharma.

Now I want to stop that application after launching 10 times, and also even user can not            launch an app after uninstall and reinstall the app.

How could I do that?

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

- Create an int variable = 0 and store it to  SharedPreferences
- In **onCreate** method, increment this variable
- Check (In **onCreate** method), if this variable > 10 - call finish()

Thats all. Hope this help.

Comment: This will not solve the OP's request to block "launch an app after uninstall and reinstall the app"

Comment: but when user uninstall the app and again reinstall it will open. how to prevent that?

Answer (score 3):

> Now i want to stop that application after launching 10 times

You are welcome to maintain some sort of counter and disable your launch activity when it should no longer be used, via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

> and also even user can not launch an app after uninstall and reinstall the app

This is not possible. You can store your counter on external storage, some place that will be retained even after an uninstall. However, the user can get rid of your counter file whenever the user wants.

Answer (score 3):

If your application uses net connection you can send a parameter to your service with unique device id. In your service you get the device id and compare with your database. If device id is not in the database (first open of app) create a row with device id and the time stamp. 
Everytime the user opens the app control the timestamp with today. If it is more than 10 days you can lock the app.

Comment: Here's a good post on "best practices" if you decide to use "device id": http://stackoverflow.com/a/2853253/1337412

Comment: but when user uninstall the app and again reinstall it will open. how to prevent that?

Comment: no it will not open. Cause device id is an unique id for every phone.
and if the user uninstall the app and reinstall it, the device id parameter will be still same. Therefore you can check timestamp (which is more than 10 days) and close the app again